# ESim (EPL Simulator) : don't know how to send data to printer

Tags: php, printing, epl, intermec

I'm using an Intermec printer PC43d set up for ESim.
And I don't know how to send data to this printer in PHP or javascript.

The printer is detected on my computer and I can print labels with bar code.

I would like to send to this printer something like that

```
N
q325
j204
I8,A,033
A0,15,0,4,1,1,N,"Title Test"
A0,35,0,4,1,1,N,"Description Test"
A0,55,0,4,1,1,N,""
B0,75,0,1,3,7,70,B,"201606040701"
P1
N
```

So I require your help please.

Comment: @deceze Thanks I just did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix by send with ajax directly to the ip address of the printer with the epl data.